# SQL Server + Dapper parameter not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

When using Dapper + SQL Server, the parameter settings not work.

FooNo、yyyyMMdd、Point are Char(8), Char(8), Char(4).

not work

```cs
    var parameters1 = new
    {
        FooNo = "00007829",
        yyyyMMdd = "20210812",
        Point = "001A"
    };
    var result = this.OpenedConn.Query(sql1, parameters1).ToList();
```

work

```cs
    sql1 = sql1.Replace("@FooNo", $@"'00007829'");
    sql1 = sql1.Replace("@yyyyMMdd", $@"'20210812'");
    sql1 = sql1.Replace("@Point", $@"'001A'");
    var result = this.OpenedConn.Query(sql1).ToList();
```

SQL

```sql
SELECT            COUNT([番号]) AS 登録数
FROM              [dbo].[Foo]
WHERE             ([施工先番号] = @FooNo) AND ([回収日] = @yyyyMMdd) AND ([ポイント] = @Point)
```

What is the correct way to assign parameters with dapper?

Comment: Instead of "not work" can you explain the issue / error message?

Comment: Please show your actual SQL query

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid error is timeout.

Comment: @Charlieface sql added. This japanese db identifier is true... I don't like this. X<

Comment: For the record: I strongly oppose the "close" here. From the description, I'm about 98% sure I know exactly what the problem is, so IMO all the relevant information is here. I don't like to unilaterally reopen (or close, for that matter) questions (my votes are kinda binding) but if anyone agrees with me - ping me (`@marc`) and I'll look again.

Comment: @MarcGravell You're probably right, but TBH with this kind of question the OP has already either lost interest or won't grasp or action your answer and is unlikely to "tick" your answer. You've already added positivley to the great internet information base here

Comment: A timeout is the query taking too long. For us to help you, we need to see the query plan (share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and the table and index definitions. @MarcGravell I'd say it could be reopened, but only when we have the relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using parameters correctly, in the first version that doesn't work. You mention that the error is a timeout. This, combined with the fact that the inline literals version works, makes me conclude that the problem here is parameter sniffing and query plan reuse.

Context: when a query plan is generated for a query, it gives a lot of weight to the parameters being used *that time* - in terms of understanding the data distributions. This is usually correct, but it has problems if the data is heavily skewed. Internally at Stack Overflow, we actually call this (lovingly) the "Jon Skeet" problem - by which I mean: users like Jon Skeet (and, to avoid false modesty, myself) have *very* different amounts of data on our profiles to most users. This can lead to problems:

1. if a query plan gets generated for a high volume user, the generated query may not work well for most "normal" users
2. if a query plan gets generated for a "normal" user, the generated query may not work well for high volume users

This manifests in slower-than-expected queries (often dramatically slower), with the observation that they work fine when executed directly: for the reason that we're forcing a different query plan!

The good new is, the solution is usually simple: "optimize for unknown"

By which I mean: add `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` after your existing query. This helps reduce the bias that atypical data can have in terms of skewing the query plan towards atypical data.

```sql
SELECT            COUNT([番号]) AS 登録数
FROM              [dbo].[Foo]
WHERE             ([施工先番号] = @FooNo) AND ([回収日] = @yyyyMMdd) AND ([ポイント] = @Point)
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```